# Wordpress custom action / filters is executed twice

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a big problem with wp.4.0.1. I make for a client a management company software, and everything is based on wordpress functions / plugins / actions & stuff.

```
class AppNoteCommand{
    function AppNoteCommand() {
        $this->table_note = 'wp_app_noteCommand';
        $this->table_stock = 'wp_app_products_stock';
        $this->instance = $this;

        add_action( 'saveNoteCommand', array( $this, 'hookSaveNoteCommand'), 10, 4);
        add_action( 'saveNoteCommand', array( $this, 'updatingStock' ), 20, 4);
    }
    function hookSaveNoteCommand( $noteFields, $clientFields, $stockFields, $dbAction ) {
        global $wpdb;
        printr($noteFields);
        if ( $dbAction == 'update' && (int) $noteFields['id'] >0 ) {
            $wpdb->update( $this->table_note, $noteFields, array( 'id' => $noteFields['id']) );
        } else $wpdb->insert( $this->table_note, $noteFields );
    }
    function updatingStock( $noteFields, $clientFields, $stockFields, $dbAction) {
        global $wpdb;
        printr($stockFields);
        if ( $dbAction != 'update' ) {
            foreach ( $stockFields['products'] as $product_id=>$stock ) {
                $wpdb->query("UPDATE {$this->table_stock} SET stock=stock-{$stock} WHERE product_id='{$product_id}' AND location_id='{$stockFields['location_id']}'");
                echo mysql_error()."<br />";
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

The main problem is action: saveNoteCommand who is executed twice on I press Save Command. The first execution is ok, but the second one generate error in MySQL ( duplicate key primary). I don't understand why wordpress executed twice a single function registered for an action, and I think this problem is generally in wordpress. All functions declared in this action is executed twice.

Can somebody help me to fix this, or to tell me if i wrong something

Comment: Why do you have `add_action()` within the function itself?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably executing it twice because WP is saving two different posts, which in term is firing the action with your procedure twice:

- the post in its new version as the post itself
- the post in its old version as a revision

Assuming so, you need to check if the ID passed to whatever is calling your action is a revision or not.

Answer (score 0):

my application doesnt have any relation with post in wordpress. Is in other directory, have other structure. The action saveNoteCommand is not executed on save_post / update_post. Is a custom action executed only in my script and only is $_POST data is submited.